# In SQL How do you find duplicates on 2 rows of 6 rows returned?

Tags: sql

[Example Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyADo.png)

I want to create a query over the example set of data attached that only returns duplicate records based on columns 2 & 6.  So for the example set of data attached I would want my results to be:

```
 1. 1 802733 EX02291617 1160304 633578 37.25 Y
 2. 1 802733 EX04081638 1160412 638232 37.52 Y
 3. 1 802733 EX04141602 1160422 639539 37.52 Y
 4. 1 806717 EX01111659 1160115 628215 83.9  Y
 5. 1 806717 EX02091664 1160212 631401 83.9  Y
```

Every time I try to use a GROUP BY function, it appears that it only works if I use all columns of returned data.  I am hopeful it does not have to be this way.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show your attempt using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also, I guess you would want to edit your question replacing 'rows' by 'columns'.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle database :

```
select * from <your_table> where rowid not in(select min(rowid) from <your_table> group by column_1,column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use self-join with GROUP BY and COUNT aggregate function:

```
SELECT a.appco, b.appvnd, a.appin, a.appcdb, a.appck, b.apppd, a.appefb 
FROM table-name AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT appvnd, apppd, COUNT(*) AS frequency
    FROM table-name
    group by appvnd, apppd
    having COUNT(*) > 1
) AS b ON a.appvnd = b.appvnd AND a.apppd = b.apppd
```

If you are querying a query result, just change the `table-name` to a subquery. For example:

```
SELECT a.appco, b.appvnd, a.appin, a.appcdb, a.appck, b.apppd, a.appefb 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM database-table-name WHERE appeft = true) AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT subx.appvnd, subx.apppd, COUNT(subx.*) AS frequency
    FROM (SELECT * FROM database-table-name WHERE appeft = true) AS subx
    group by subx.appvnd, subx.apppd
    having COUNT(subx*) > 1
) AS b ON a.appvnd = b.appvnd AND a.apppd = b.apppd
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me direction.  In the end, I could not quite figure out your solution, as it kept giving me errors, but most likely that's on me keying incorrectly.  However it did lead me to a solution that worked,(which was most likely the same as the solution your provided)

Comment: This was essentially my solution                                                    SELECT 
 "APPCO#",
 APPVND,
 "APPIN#",
 APPCDT,
 "APPCK#",
 "APPPD$",
 APPEFT 
FROM 
 DSFILESCO.APPMTTRN APPMTTRN 
WHERE 
  CONCAT( "APPPD$", APPVND ) IN( 
  SELECT 
   CONCAT( "APPPD$", APPVND ) 
  FROM 
   DSFILESCO.APPMTTRN APPMTTRN 
  WHERE 
   CONCAT( APPMTTRN."APPPD$", APPMTTRN.APPVND ) IS NOT NULL
   AND APPMTTRN.APPVOD = ' ' 
  
  GROUP BY 
   CONCAT( "APPPD$", APPVND ) 
  HAVING 
   COUNT( * ) > 1 
   ) 
ORDER BY 
 2, 
 6

Comment: We didn't have the same naming convention and SQL syntax, I guess. But glad I helped. I feel that the query can still be optimized for performance, although it would require a lengthy SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE ROWID IN (
                SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM Table_Name
                GROUP BY 2ndColumn_Name,6thColumn_Name
                );
Inner Query execute first: it will select only the maximum ROWID among each group which is formed by 2ndColumn_Name & 6thColumn_Name combinely.

Outer Query execute next: It will display all the distinct records.

if you want to see all the duplicate records then in outer query use "NOT IN" instead of "IN" operator.

ROWID is unique for each records inserted into Database i.e provided by Database itself internally.